# Which is better design for a JSON: Using arrays of objects or objects directly

Tags: json

Which is the better data format for a JSON. The requirement is to be able to store and retrieve information about how many projects are deployed on to a server.

Object-Based Design

```
{ 
   "Server1":{
        "project1":{
            "buildNo":"290",
            "deployed":"12/12/2012"
        },
        "project2":{
            "buildNo":"291",
            "deployed":"11/12/2012"
        },
        "project3":{
            "buildNo":"209",
            "deployed":"11/12/2012"
        }
  }
}
```

Array-Based Design

```
{ 
   "Server1":[
        {"project1":{
            "buildNo":"290",
            "deployed":"12/12/2012"
        }},
        {"project2":{
            "buildNo":"291",
            "deployed":"11/12/2012"
        }},
        {"project3":{
            "buildNo":"209",
            "deployed":"11/12/2012"
        }}
    ]
}
```

Please do let me know your thoughts for or against either of these approaches.

Comment: based upon your accessibility and requirement.

Comment: Whatever represents you application's data.

Comment: Depends on corresponding data representation at server side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the order of projects significant?

If it is, then an array is the simplest way to represent that.

If it is not, then array requires an unnecessary preprocessing step to map array indexes to project names before you can access them by name.

Answer (score 1):

My thoughts:

1. Parsing: 
      Both are of similar complexity.
2. Adding/Deleting:
      Both are of similar complexity
3. Readability/Representation of Information:
      The first indicates a fixed structure whereas the second suggests that projects may be added removed later.